# How to add elements to a list recursively without the list resetting to empty with each recursive call?

Tags: python, list, recursion, directory

I'm trying to recursively loop over directories and subdirectories to find all the files within the mother directory.

This is for Python 3. I have tried testing whether the given path is a directory or file. If it's a file I append the path to a list and if it's a directory I call the function back on it so that it can add any files in it to the list to get a full list of paths to the files in the first directory.

```py
import os,csv,json
def find_file(path):
    paths = []
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        cont = os.listdir(path)
        for x in cont:
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,x)):
                if x.startswith("."):
                    continue
                paths.append(os.path.join(path,x))
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path,x)):
                find_file(os.path.join(path,x))
    else:
        paths.append(path)
    return(paths)
```

What happens is that it returns all the file elements from the immediate mother directory but if there are directories within the mother directory, none of the files from that directory will end up in the list.

Comment: You create and append to a new list on each call: `paths = []`, then you do nothing with the returned value of the recursive calls inside your function. Probably want to do something with the result of `result = find_file(os.path.join(path,x))` ...

Answer (score 0):

When you call `find_file` recursively, you have to append all its results to `paths`.

```
import os,csv,json
def find_file(path):
    paths = []
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        cont = os.listdir(path)
        for x in cont:
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,x)):
                if x.startswith("."):
                    continue
                paths.append(os.path.join(path,x))
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path,x)):
                paths += find_file(os.path.join(path,x))
    else:
        paths.append(path)
    return(paths)
```

Another way to do it is to pass `paths` as an argument.

```
import os,csv,json
def find_file(path, paths = None):
    if paths is None:
        paths = []
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        cont = os.listdir(path)
        for x in cont:
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,x)):
                if x.startswith("."):
                    continue
                paths.append(os.path.join(path,x))
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path,x)):
                find_file(os.path.join(path,x), paths)
    else:
        paths.append(path)
    return(paths)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried the first way and it worked perfectly! Much appreciated.